# Creating a file with open() but have not permissions to modify it in C

Tags: c, file-permissions

I'am creating a text file in C that way

```
fd = open("results.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IROTH);
    if (fd<0){
        perror("open error");
        abort();
    }
    write(fd,msg,strlen(msg)+1);
```

But when I'm trying to write something else in it I have not permissions . Could anyone help ?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `err_sys`?  Is it possible the `open` fails but you aren't logging this or exiting your program?

Comment: @simonc I just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `fd=open("results.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0777);`

instead of

```
fd = open("results.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IROTH);
```

Comment: Is 0777 the int value of S_IROTH or something like that?

Comment: check that in your header file, it should be S_IRWXO

Answer (score 1):

There should be problem in flags, because you are creating file, you are using flag

```
O_CREAT
```

so now you need to specify access mode, as mentioned in man page. You specified just

```
S_IROTH
```

So you made it just readonly for others. So when you open it again you CAN'T write.
So you should also define write modes, also read for user etc.

```
S_IRUSR | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR
```

Se man page for details.